# Unicode Decode Error: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2

Tags: python, pygame

Я тут написал небольшую игру.

```
import pygame
import random

width = 800
height = 600
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("The best game ever")

car_img = pygame.image.load("car.png")
barrel_img = pygame.image.load("barrel.png")
menu_img = pygame.image.load("menu.jpg")
b_play = pygame.image.load("button1.png")
b_quit = pygame.image.load("button2.png")
b_play_hover = pygame.image.load("button1_hover.png")
b_quit_hover = pygame.image.load("button2_hover.png")
b_continue = pygame.image.load("button3.png")
b_continue_hover = pygame.image.load("button3_hover.png")
b_quit2 = pygame.image.load("button4.png")
b_quit2_hover = pygame.image.load("button4_hover.png")
b_replay = pygame.image.load("button5.png")
b_replay_hover = pygame.image.load("button5_hover.png")

crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("crash.ogg")
bg_music = pygame.mixer.music.load("Fluffle Puff Tales - PFUDOR.ogg")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

def barrels_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("copperlategothic", 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

def barrel(objX, objY):
    gameDisplay.blit(barrel_img, (objX, objY))

def car(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(car_img, (x, y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("copperlategothic.ttf", 115)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    textRect.center = ((width / 2, height / 2 - 200))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def crash():
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    message_display("You crashed")

    crashed = True
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    while crashed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                    crashed = False
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if 355 + 100 > mouse[0] > 355 and 200 + 25 > mouse[1] > 200:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_replay_hover, (width / 2 - 45, 200))
            if click[0] == 1:
                gameLoop()
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_replay, (width / 2 - 45, 200))

        if 355 + 100 > mouse[0] > 355 and 260 + 50 > mouse[1] > 260:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit2_hover, (width / 2 - 45, 260))
            if click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit2, (width / 2 - 45, 260))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def menu():
    menu = True

    while menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            menu_x = width / 2
            menu_y = height / 2

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        gameDisplay.blit(menu_img, (menu_x - 400, menu_y - 300))

        if 375 + 100 > mouse[0] > 375 and 200 + 50 > mouse[1] > 200:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_play_hover, (width / 2 - 25, 200))
            if click[0] == 1:
                gameLoop()
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_play, (width / 2 - 25, 200))

        if 375 + 100 > mouse[0] > 375 and 260 + 50 > mouse[1] > 260:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit_hover, (width / 2 - 25, 260))
            if click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit, (width / 2 - 25, 260))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def pause():
    paused = True
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                    paused = False
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if 355 + 100 > mouse[0] > 355 and 200 + 17 > mouse[1] > 200:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_continue_hover, (width / 2 - 45, 200))
            if click[0] == 1:
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                paused = False
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_continue, (width / 2 - 45, 200))

        if 355 + 100 > mouse[0] > 355 and 260 + 50 > mouse[1] > 260:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit2_hover, (width / 2 - 45, 260))
            if click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            gameDisplay.blit(b_quit2, (width / 2 - 45, 260))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def gameLoop():

    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    x = (width * .45)
    y = (height * .8)

    x_change = 0
    y_change = 0

    vel = 10

    barrel_startX = random.randrange(0, width - 70)
    barrel_startY = -600
    barrelSpeed = 4

    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x_change -= vel
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change += vel
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        barrel(barrel_startX, barrel_startY)
        barrel_startY += barrelSpeed

        car(x, y)

        barrels_dodged(dodged)

        if x > width - 64 or x < 0:
            crash()

        if barrel_startY > height:
            barrel_startY = 0 - 95
            barrel_startX = random.randrange(0, width - 95)
            dodged += 1
            barrelSpeed += .5

        if y < barrel_startY + 95:
            if x > barrel_startX and x < barrel_startX + 70 or x + 64 > barrel_startX and x + 64 < barrel_startX + 70:
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

menu()
gameLoop()
```

Потом создал файл setup.py

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("The Car.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="The Car",
    options={"build.exe":{"packages":["pygame"],
                           "include_files":["barrel.png", "butoon1.png", "button1_hover.png", "button2.png",
                                             "button2_hover.png", "button3.png", "button3_hover.png", "button4.png",
                                             "button4_hover.png", "button5.png", "button5_hover.png", "car.png",
                                             "crash.ogg", "Fluffle Puff Tales - PFUDOR.ogg", "menu.jpg"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

И после того, как я скомпилировал файл и попытался открыть игру через exe файл, то у меня открылась игра с черным экраном и тут же закрылась. Консоль тоже появляется и сразу исчезает. Еле как смог заскринить. Короче выдало такую ошибку:

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\codecs.py" line 300 in decode,
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
Unicode Decode Error: 'utf8'  codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2
```

Comment: нет необходимости весь код включать. Постарайтесь создать [*минимальный* пример кода, который демонстрирует ошибку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ошибку, которую я не вижу

Comment: чтобы увидеть вывод программы, из консоли запустите её. Если не ясно как, то задайте отдельный вопрос—специально об этом.

Comment: Дело в том, что консоль открывается и потом сразу же закрывается

Comment: Шаг №1: открыть консоль Шаг №2: запустить *в уже открытой консоле* скрипт. (Для тренировки можно записать `print("Hello world")` в `hello.py` файл и запустить его так чтобы надпись `Hello world` осталась на экране . Если не ясно как это сделать—задайте отдельный вопрос—специально об этом.)

Comment: @ColorBl4de: Ну так уменьшайте размер программы, выкидывая куски один за другим, пока не найдёте изменение, убирающее ошибку или не упростите программу до хелловорлда. Кто-то должен это сделать, и скорее всего именно вы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить начало файла на:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
import random
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?